# Emulating ROW_NUMBER() in MariaDB sql query returns null when executing query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sequelpro

I'm trying to get the row number of records in my database table, I'm using a variable and am executing the query, I get no errors, but get a null column for `num` and need to know where I'm going wrong to resolve this:

```sql
SET @row_number = 0; 
SELECT 
    token,
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num
FROM
    tlp_queue_manager_schedulers
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a session variable as a derived table and cross join it with the main table to emulate row_number.

Try:

```
SELECT token,
       (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num  
FROM tlp_queue_manager_schedulers,
    (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
ORDER BY token ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=5414551f42d42844d6db42592683d8f4)

Worth reading: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: This works well which is fantastic, but when running this inside of something like Cake PHP as a query, the `num` result is inside of a key called `0`, how could I combine this and put it next to `token`?